# python + write the right CSV format

Tags: python, linux

The following python simple program ,

get from the user the number of users

And each user asked about **UserAge, UserID, UserSalry**

Finally the users details will write to the csv file

but in the CSV file I see that format

```
  ['34','3245353','2312$']
```

In place to get this format:

```
  34,3245353,2312$
```

Please advice what I need to change in my code in order to get the following format

```
  34,3245353,2312$
```

.

my python code:

```
 userinput = input ("print the number of users:")
 NumbersOfUsers = int(userinput)

 counter = 0 
 array = []

 while counter < NumbersOfUsers :

 list = ( 'UserAge','UserID','UserSalry' )

  for index in list:
      A = input (index)
      array.append(A)
      UserAge = int(A)
  counter = counter + 1

 print (array)

 arrResults=str(array)


file = open('file.csv','w')
file.write(arrResults)
file.close()
```

.

( Example 2) of the code after update ( according to Burhan Khalid )

```
userinput = input ("print the number of users:")
NumbersOfUsers = int(userinput)

counter = 0 


while counter < NumbersOfUsers :

    Listarr = ( 'UserAge','UserID','UserSalry' )

    for index in Listarr:
       A = input (index)
       array.append(A)
    counter = counter + 1

print (array)



 file = open('file.csv','w')
 file.write(','.join(array))
 file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is because you are doing this `arrResults=str(array)` - which converts the array to a string representation, and that includes the `[ ]`.

You don't need to do that at all, just:

```
file = open('file.csv', 'w')
file.write(','.join(array))
file.close()
```

Don't use `list` as the name of a variable, as it is the name of a built-in function.

Finally, this line: `UserAge = int(A)` is not doing anything useful, you can remove it from your code.

If this isn't homework, you should use the `csv` module:

```
import csv

with open('file.csv', 'w') as f:
   writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
   writer.writerows(array)
```

Comment: hi Khalid , see my update , but on the example 2 I still get the same results -:(

Answer (score 1):

You can use csv writer in python as follows:

```
import csv

...

with open('file.csv', 'wb') as write_file:
    file_writer = csv.writer(write_file)
    file_writer.writerow(array)
```

This way, you won't have to convert the array to a string.